# Android NDK Camera - Timestamp at mid exposure time

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera

I am using the [Android NDK camera sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/camera) and extracting the timestamp for the image using `AImage_getTimestamp(image, &image_timestamp)` [after an image is acquired](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/camera/basic/src/main/cpp/camera_engine.cpp#L161), where I believe that the timestamp refers to the instant where the frame is fully captured (end of exposure). However, I would like to also calculate the timestamp for the mid exposure time. The reason for this is that this is a common practice when performing vision-based state estimation as described [in this paper](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/81914/eth-8003-01.pdf), which I am interested in doing.

So I was wondering if there is any way to extract the timestamp for the beginning of the exposure so I could do the calculation of the mid exposure time given the current timestamp I have for the end of exposure? I tried searching the Android NDK camera documentation but could not find such value.

Thanks for the help!